# How to cast Dynamically the instance of classes in Android

Tags: java, android, class, casting, type-conversion

Below i have given a short sample code. But I am using this in switch case for click events on **5** different views. And for every case I need to check the instance of class before proceeding.

```
public class OnResetListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ViewHolder oHolder;

    OnResetListener(ViewHolder holder) {
        oHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(oHolder instanceof FolderVH){

            ((FolderVH) oHolder).viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);

        } else if(oHolder instanceof NoteVH) {

            ((NoteVH) oHolder).viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);

        } else if(oHolder instanceof CheckListVH) {

            ((CheckListVH) oHolder).viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the classes are extended from **`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`** and named as **`FolderVH`**, **`NoteVH`** and **`CheckListVH`**. All these extended classes are having *exact same structure* but different value assignments.

Is there a way that i can dynamically cast the class instance ... Say like

`if(oHolder instanceof FolderVH) oHolder = ((FolderVH) oHolder);`

and then i simply use `oHolder` where ever required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make all three `FolderVH`, `NoteVH` and `CheckListVH` extend a common base class, say `ViewPagerVH`, which contains the `viewPager` field:

```
class ViewPagerVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  public ViewPager viewPager;
}

class FolderVH extends ViewPagerVH { ... }
// etc.
```

Then you can just check like this:

```
if (oHolder instanceof ViewPagerVH) {
  ((ViewPagerVH) oHolder).viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
}
```

Comment: How can i assign value to `viewPager` in `ViewPagerVH` from the extended `FolderVH`, `NoteVH` or `CheckListVH`?

Comment: Just use `viewPager = ...;` as usual. You should really learn about inheritance in Java, it's pretty essential.

Comment: Sure @Thomas. Actually right now working on the same :) By the way thanks for the answer. It worked.... Just on more question. Is it a good practice to assign it directly like `viewPager = ...;` or via a method calling? say like `setViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: Using a method is generally considered better practice, because you can then make the field `private`, which helps with encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

If all your viewHolders have same structure I would concider creating one parent class that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder (Let's call it "ParentViewHolder"). Then your viewHolders should extend your "ParentViewHolder".
At the end you can always cast oHolder to the "ParentViewHolder" class and everything should work.
Hope I understood and answedr your question. :)